# Gaussian cumulative density function through Taylor expansion

Tags: java, math, numerical-methods, taylor-series

I'm developing software in Java. I have a Gaussian distribution and I must compute the cumulative density function (CDF).

Since the formula of CDF involves ERF function which should formally be computed by integral (it's horrible to compute it in Java), I've found a Taylor series expansion very interesting to my case:

[image: erf-taylor]

Let's get focused on ERF computation. Here is the code I've written:

```
private static double getErf(double x){
    double sumTaylorExpansion = x;
    double prevSumTaylorExpansion;
    double num1 = 1; //first factor of numerator
    double num2 = x; //second factor of numerator
    double den1 = 1; //first factor of denominator
    double den2 = 1; //second factor of denominator
    int n = 1; //cycle invariant
    do {
        prevSumTaylorExpansion = sumTaylorExpansion;
        num1 *= -1;
        num2 *= Math.pow(x, 2);
        den1 += 2;
        den2 *= n;
        sumTaylorExpansion += ((num1 * num2) / (den1 * den2));
        n++;
    }
    while (Math.abs(sumTaylorExpansion - prevSumTaylorExpansion) > 0.00000000000001);
    return (2/Math.sqrt(Math.PI))*sumTaylorExpansion;
}
```

If the input of this method is for example 1.5, the result is correct. But if I try with input 32 it returns NaN. It is obviously a problem related to numerical analysis due to the growing values involved in the formula. Which could be an approach to compute an approximated result?

Note that I cannot stop the cycle before I get NaN because sometimes the precision does not reach even the first decimal digit. So this approach cannot reach an acceptable approximation.

Comment: Are there any alternatives?

Comment: But my problem is related with Java implementation :(

Comment: 1. Does the series converge when x = 32?   2. some suggestions for performance improvement: `x*x` is more efficient than `Math.pow(x, 2)` and since this is unchanging it should be calculated outside the loop.

Comment: 1.This Taylor-series always converges. 2. The update of variable num2 cannot be calculated outside the loop! It must be updated each time. So, now the problem is not the power x^2.

Comment: I mean calculate `x*x` and store it in a variable outside the loop and use that variable inside the loop instead of calculating `x*x` inside every time. (It's probably going to be optimized by the JIT compiler anyway so you probably won't see any significant performance gain.)

Comment: Even though (as you say) the series always converges, num2 and den2 can become individually very large, even if num2/dem2 is not very large. You can do the calculation one bit at a time instead of calculating num2 and den2, so that you never get such really large numbers. Do a multiplication, then a division, then another multiplication, etc.

Comment: If you need the CDF of the standard normal distribution to be accurate in the tails, you would want to use `erfc`, not `erf`: normcdf(x) = 0.5*erfc(-sqrt(0.5)*x).

Answer (score 0):

Since this algorithm is not practically useful when the x is high I've used an alternative implementation which gives an approximates result. For my purposes it is ok! The formula is the following:
[erf-approximated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIhME.png)